# jquery escaping quotes not quite right

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have attempted escaping quotes out from this jquery bit of code and I'm not quite getting it. As well as the correct answer could I get the format for escaping quotes in jquery? Specifically I'm only trying to put the rdata.result[i].name variable into a string to pass it over. Thanks!

```
filling += "<a onclick=\"inserttictac("+rdata.result[i].uid+","+rdata.script[0]+",\'"+rdata.result[i].name+"\',"+rdata.result[i].front+","+rdata.result[i].back+","+rdata.result[i].side+")\'>Select</a>";
```

Comment: You could probably make your life easier if you didn't use inline Javascript, but instead defined the handler with `$("selector").click()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape the single quotes, only the double quotes.

You are using double quotes for string definition, so only escape those.

```
filling += "<a onclick=\"inserttictac("+rdata.result[i].uid+","+rdata.script[0]+",'"+rdata.result[i].name+"',"+rdata.result[i].front+","+rdata.result[i].back+","+rdata.result[i].side+")\">Select</a>";
```

Comment: apparently I get this in the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: escape it . other wise chars line " ' create issues

Comment: @user3045858 Try now, just noticed you were using a single quote for the end of your string concatenation. I've edited answer to double, with escape.